# Throttling producers in AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Is there any PaaS way to throttle ingest into Kinesis from clients, e.g. to prevent DDoS? I would rather not have to filter through an EC2 instance. Maybe API or Lambda somehow... The idea is to enforce a rate limit, like X messages per minute or hour.